# Synchronization between two calls of a threaded_irq

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, thread-safety, linux-device-driver, interrupt

If a `threaded_irq` from a Linux device driver accesses a global variable to read and write and nothing else has access to that variable, is synchronization necessary?

For example if the interrupt triggers twice, will there be two threads trying to read/write the shared variable or will there be a single thread that will be triggered twice?

I know that interrupt handlers need not be reentrant because the interrupt line is masked out on all processors, but that does not apply to a `threaded_irq` which runs in process context.

Comment: It depends. Without code it's hard to say. Vote to close.

Comment: The calls to the threaded handler function will all be from the same thread created when the threaded IRQ is requested, so it need not be reentrant. The thread tests and clears a flag and calls the handler function if the flag was set. An interrupt trigger can set the flag again at any time after the flag is cleared but if the thread is still handling the previous trigger, it will not notice the new trigger until the handler function has returned.

Comment: @0andriy what code do you want? It is a question about how threaded irqs work. You either know if several threads are created or not, in which case it if of course hard to say. Thanks for the constructive answers.

Comment: @IanAbbott we have _one shot_, don't we? But I want the OP to learn something and not repeating same question without any new information or homework done.

Comment: This sire requires a code snippet to discuss.

Comment: @0andriy A code snippet isn't required for a general coding question. For example, the question on the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) page doesn't have a code snippet.

Comment: So is the answer to this question that threaded interrupts are not re-entrant? IE a second can't be spawned while the first is still running?